# Executable jar in spring for cron job without boot

Tags: spring-batch

I built an application using spring cron jobs using boot and is working fine.
But I want to create a jar that will be executed via command line to execute my cron jobs.
I don't want to use spring boot and xml.

I searched ,but found nothing

How can I do this? I am not getting from where I should start

Answer (score 0):

You can have fun and add all hierarchy dependencies from parent and all children depencies:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-batch/1.4.0.RELEASE

```
<!-- Spring Batch -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

It was long and not funny job to get juste the necessary dependencies.